# Scroll mail's body like gmail with fixed footer using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail, footer, fixed

Scroll mail's body like gmail with fixed footer using java script http://dev.alpaca.org.ua/gm.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/n51kbuha/). Here only using `css` and `html`.

Comment: But down block with bottons must be fixed, when contenteditable area higher than the window